# Fetching WordPress posts using Json API

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I am new to the whole JSON thing and currently working on an Android App for my WordPress site using Intel XDK.
I have installed WordPress' [JSON API Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) which enables me to get recent posts using **http://example.com/?json=get_recent_posts**
What I don't know is how to display them on my App. I am new and need your kind help. Please help me out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Watch this tutorial on how to do just that. [Intel® XDK App Designer - Using Services Datafeed in App Designer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-services-datafeed-in-app-designer)
2. When HE drills down in the Web Services section for Rotten Tomatoes© api info, YOU need to select: API Explorer Sandbox > Methods > GET
3. Paste in the URL of the JSON API from WordPress:  example.com/?json=get_recent_posts

Follow the tutorial exact (mind your drag and drop in XDK..) and you will accomplish this with ease.

IMPORTANT! *** *TIP*** - When selecting Angular or Backbone options in the data-bindings process of the tutorial, I found that if I selected Angular.js MVC framework, I was getting the `<p>` tag in from my imported `content` and/or `excerpt` data from the JSON output. So, to combat this issue I simply selected the other option of **Backbone.js** instead and all the p tags went away and also some other small formatting issues i saw.

**In addition**, to do a (*obviously needed*, auto-refresh on post/page/anything you are pulling in from JSON API plugin) ****Copy paste link ---> software.intel.com/en-us/videos/pull-to-refresh-in-framework-7

**Framework 7 Templates to help out** ****Copy paste link ---> idangero.us/framework7/examples/#.VqjrVVMrJFw